# How to hide collapsible Bootstrap 4 navbar on click in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created this Navbar using boostsrap 4, but i want it to get collapse when i click on the link,
Any way to do this? Thanks.
please help me i'm stuck here.

````
import moon from '../Images/moon.ico'
import  {  NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'



const NavBar = () => {
    return(
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <NavLink to='/' className="navbar-brand"><img src={moon} alt="logo" className="logo-img"/></NavLink>
  <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul className="navbar-nav">
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink to="/" className="nav-link">Home</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink to="/about"  className="nav-link">About</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink to='/skill'  className="nav-link">Skills</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink to="/project"  className="nav-link">Projects</NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    )
}

export default  NavBar```
````

Comment: you could set an ID on the navbar to collapse and then add and onclick event to the link, triggering a javascript function that sets display to none for that element?